# I can't get the attribute name of an abstract class in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

This is the class:

```
public abstract class DbAttributeInstance
{
    public static DbAttribute AALLAN;

    public static DbAttribute AANGXZ;

    public static DbAttribute AANGYZ;

    public static DbAttribute ABLE;

    public static DbAttribute ABOP;
...
}
```

I used the following code to get the member name, but got nothing:

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(DbAttributeInstance).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
```

The final purpose of this operation is to test the class `DbAttributeInstance`'s every attributes' validity, like this:

```
if (elem.IsAttributeValid(DbAttributeInstance.GEOM)) then...
```

but there are too many attributes in `DbAttributeInstance` so I can't test them one by one.
I want to test every member by using the following form:

```
//original way to be replaced
elem.IsAttributeValid(DbAttributeInstance.member1)
elem.IsAttributeValid(DbAttributeInstance.member1)
elem.IsAttributeValid(DbAttributeInstance.member1)
elem.IsAttributeValid(DbAttributeInstance.member1)
elem.IsAttributeValid(DbAttributeInstance.member1)
...
//new
foreach (member in DbAttributeInstance's members) {
    elem.IsAttributeValid(member)
}
```

Comment: Do you get any kind of error?

Comment: no. thank you and  I've found all info

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use another flag, according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=net-5.0):

There is a `BindingFlags.Static`.